# C++ duplicate symbol linker error with proper include guards?

Tags: c++, include-guards, duplicate-symbol

I'm writing a program to test concrete inheritance, though I cannot resolve the duplicate symbol linker error Clang returns. My understanding is duplicate symbols is always the result of incorrect includes/guards. I have triple checked my includes/guards, but I cannot find any errors. Could the duplicate symbol be the result of something other than include guards? Many thanks, as I grow my programming skills I intend to contribute here frequently.

.h

```
#ifndef POINTARRAY_H
#define POINTARRAY_H
#include "array.h"

namespace Jules
{
    namespace Containers
    {
        class PointArray: public Array<Point>
        {
        public:
            PointArray();    //default constructor
            ~PointArray();    //destructor
            PointArray(const PointArray& p);    //copy constructor
            PointArray(const int i);    //constructor with input argument
            PointArray& operator = (const PointArray& source);    //assignment operator
            double Length() const;    //length between points in array
        };
    }
}
#ifndef POINTARRAY_CPP
#include "PointArray.cpp"
#endif
#endif
```

.cpp

```
#ifndef POINTARRAY_CPP
#define POINTARRAY_CPP
#include "PointArray.h"

using namespace Jules::CAD;

namespace Jules
{
    namespace Containers
    {
        PointArray::PointArray() : Array<Point>()    //default constructor
        {
        }

        PointArray::~PointArray()    //destructor
        {
        }

        PointArray::PointArray(const PointArray& p) : Array<Point>(p)    //copy constructor
        {
        }

        PointArray::PointArray(const int i) : Array<Point>(i)    //constructor with input argument
        {
        }

        PointArray& PointArray::operator = (const PointArray& source)    //assignment operator
        {
            if (this == &source)
                return *this;
            PointArray::operator = (source);
            return *this;
        }

        double PointArray::Length() const
        {
        double lengthOfPoints = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Array::Size()-1; i++)
            lengthOfPoints += (*this)[i].Distance((*this)[i+1]);
            return lengthOfPoints;
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Update: Thank you everyone for your help. I understand the mechanics now.

Comment: Include guards are not related to multiple definition link errors. (You might get multiple declaration/definition compilation errors before the link stage is reached, without them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `#include`ing your `.cpp` file in your `.h`, which will result in the `.cpp` code being included in every file that uses the `.h` (hence the duplicate symbols). You are also misusing include guards: only header files need include guards; `.cpp` files should never have them.

Comment: I'm supposed to include the .cpp in .h because of the template. It was specific in the instructions to do so. But I still call the .h via the guard in PointArray.h

Comment: @kits: Your `PointArray` class is not a template.

Comment: But if it was a template, than the guards were correct yes? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include the `cpp` file in your header. If you do this, every translation unit which includes your header will end up with a definition of the class, e.g., `PointArray` leading to the linker error with multiple definitions.

Remove this from your header.

```
#ifndef POINTARRAY_CPP
#include "PointArray.cpp"
#endif
#endif
```